# Core i5 vs. i7 in respect to overclocking potential

Tags: intel-core-i7, overclocking, intel-core-i5

I'm hesitating between getting a i5 760 or a i7 860, both of which have 4 cores at 2.8GHz.

The i5 is considerably cheaper -- what is the downside to it? Is it far more limited in the amount of overclocking it can take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main factor in overclocking is the quality of the CPU that you get, which is a matter of pure luck.

I quote from [OverClocking Risks](http://www.speedupnow.com/pc-boost/cpu-booster.html):

> Usually processors in the lower range
>   are produced with the same
>   manufacturing process as the CPUs sold
>   in the mid to high range. The higher
>   rated CPUs are factory overclocked and
>   tested, then sold for a premium. Many
>   users will buy the cheaper processor
>   and over clock it to nearly the same
>   speeds of the premium CPUs. This is a
>   great deal if and only if you are
>   lucky enough to get a CPU that just
>   missed the premium cut during initial
>   factory testing. Sometimes, you will
>   be stuck with a CPU that only over
>   clocks slightly above its rating.

However, you should be warned that with overclocking, you risk one day to burn-out completely your CPU. Luckily, there are warning signs that shouldn't be ignored, such as the occasional unexplainable crash.

Answer (score 1):

[This review](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/hardware/articles/48391.aspx) should help you out in figuring out what the differences are between the 2 processor families. In a nutshell:

> Core i5 is clearly meant to be a more mainstream processor. Those who use their computers for heavily multi-thread applications will miss **hyper-threading** and the **triple-channel memory**, which means that a Core i7 on an LGA1366 socket will be best.

So, Core i7 CPUs offer higher memory bandwidth. I don't think there are extreme differences in overclocking potential between the 2 families; I think it's more of a case by case basis for each CPU.